# how to solve No CMAKE_Fortran_COMPILER could be found.?

Tags: cmake

how to solve  No CMAKE_Fortran_COMPILER could be found. ?

> CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:3 (project):   No CMAKE_Fortran_COMPILER
>   could be found.
>
> Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the
>   environment   variable "FC" or the CMake cache entry
>   CMAKE_Fortran_COMPILER to the full   path to the compiler, or to the
>   compiler name if it is in the PATH.
>
> -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

Answer (score 9):

it's probably missing **gfortran** Try installing the gfortran using the following command:

```
$ sudo apt install gfortran
```

Try installing the gfortran. It maybe works!